# General recursion instead of mutation

Tags: f#

Can this function be implemented using general recursion instead of mutation/ref cell?

```
let bundle f (s: _ ref) x =
    let v = f s.Value x
    s.Value <- v
    v
```

A function like this gives me a dirty shortcut to implementing say Stream.scan wherever I only have Stream.map.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re looking for a pure functional solution, I believe the answer is no. In the language of typeclasses, `map` means you’ve got a [functor](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functor), while `fold` or `scan` imply that you have a [foldable](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldable). Not all functors are foldable. (A type that is both a functor and foldable is called “traversable”.)